# how to do date Localization using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, localization, internationalization

I have model which has date in DD/MM/YYYY format i.e how it is saved in DB format.

Now while displaying to german user I Convert it DD.MM.YYYY and show it in textbox. But while saving back to DB i need to convert it in old format.

As i am using angular the new date is updated in model.

Could someone suggest or give some mock code for this.

Comment: not sure I understand the 3rd paragraph line BUT have you looked into angular moment

Comment: I meant as the value is binded using ng-model in textbox and it shown in format DD.MM.YYYY format.  This same goes and get updated in model. But in dB I am saving date in DD/MM/YYYY format so what I want is, that value should get updated in old format in model.